# How to plot an RG flow

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

How can I plot this in latex? [image]

Source: Fig 8.3 in Giuseppe Mussardo - Statistical Field Theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two easy ways to achieve the curved lines. You can define angles of the line at the start and end points relative to the node like so:

```
\draw (A) to[out=80,in=130] (B);
```

Or you can use Bezier curves to gain a bit more control like so:

```
\draw (A) .. controls (1,-.5) .. (B);
```

The arrows in the middle can be achieved using decorations and the letters by using `label`s on the nodes.

Here is a starting point illustrating how to do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        edge/.style={circle,fill,minimum size=1.5mm,inner sep=0pt},
        every path/.style={draw,thin,decoration={markings,mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},>=stealth},
        every label/.style={font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
        x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \node[edge,label=93:A] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[edge,label=15:B] (B) at (2,0.5) {};
        \node[edge,label=89:C] (C) at (1,-1) {};
        
        \path[postaction={decorate}] (A) -- (B);
        \path[postaction={decorate}] (A) -- (C);
        \path[postaction={decorate}] (C) -- (B);
        
        % Using angles
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (A) to[out=80,in=130] (B);
        
        % Using Bezier curves
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (A) .. controls (1,-.5) .. (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code will result in something like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: If you want to save yourself some time and repetitive lines of code, you can optimise this using `\foreach` loops, like e.g. so:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        edge/.style={circle,fill,minimum size=1.5mm,inner sep=0pt},
        every path/.style={draw,thin,decoration={markings,mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},>=stealth},
        every label/.style={font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
        x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \node[edge,label=93:A] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[edge,label=15:B] (B) at (2,0.5) {};
        \node[edge,label=89:C] (C) at (1,-1) {};
        
        \foreach \i/\j in {A/B, A/C, C/B}{
            \path[postaction={decorate}] (\i) -- (\j);
        }

        % Using angles
        \foreach \i/\j in {80/130, 350/220}{
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (A) to[out=\i,in=\j] (B);
        }
        
        % Using Bezier curves
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (A) .. controls (1,-.5) .. (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```